# How to check if a text exists in an element using python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am able to locate the element of a web page using Python and Selenium? Is there a way I can find if a particular text exists in the very same element.

Below is my code:

```
import datetime, time
from selenium import webdriver
from pathlib import Path

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
today = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(today)
driver.get("http://mylink.com")
uname = driver.find_element_by_name("UserName")
pwd = driver.find_element_by_name("Password")
uname.send_keys("@.com")
pwd.send_keys("pwd")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitButton"]').click()

time.sleep(30)

element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/span/font/font')
```

Belos is the error that I get.

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/span/font/font"}
```

Comment: Share your current code, HTML, desired output...

Comment: need more input from OP , share HTML , and what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a particular text to exist in an element you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//nodeTag[contains(.,'text_to_be_present')]")))
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element`? See the docs: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.. But would this work even if I have not been able to locate the element.